# How to find numbers in images and read them?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, python-tesseract

I have this picture:

[image: Structure with painted number]

and this is my Region of Interest:

[image]

which is a number that I would like to recognize and "read".

I don't know why I can't detect it using pytesseract.
Even though I preprocess it and get this image free of noise:

[image: preprocessed and binary image]

Here is the configuration I am using to read it:

1. Only numbers;
2. One char;

   ```py
   text = pytesseract.image_to_string(number_5,  lang='eng',config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
   ```

And still, I just get `\n\x0c` as an answer.

I would like to ask for some tips on how to recognize images with unique characters (only numbers in this case);

And also a question about number detection. Is there a model that can search for numbers in a photo and return a bounding box of where they are located?

Comment: Your questions is asking for different things. If you would like to have support regarding your `pytesseract` issue, I would suggest to upload a complete minimal working example (including the image) that demonstrates what is failing. In addition, [here](https://paperswithcode.com/task/scene-text-detection) you will find a collection of text detection models. I would assume that they also work for sequences of digits.

Comment: Andre, thanks for your comments. I am already taking a look at this collection of text detection models. Regarding the complete minimum work example, it is right there. This number 5, for example, cannot be read by the algorithm. When I try it with a photo downloaded from the internet, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

One way of detecting `5` in the image would be masking the image.

You could use [Thresholding Operations using inRange](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html). First, we need to find the upper and lower bounds values for thresholding. After few trials, I figured that the following is suitable for recognition.

```
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 0, 175]), np.array([179, 255, 255]))
```

- the lower bound is `np.array([0, 0, 175])`
- the upper bound is `np.array([179, 255, 255])`

The result will be:

[image]

Here above we can see the number `5` clearly.

Now we can apply the following [processing](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) methods.

```py
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=1)
thr = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)
```

The result will be:

[image]

Now if we apply `tesseract`

```py
d = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 10")
```

The [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oisXh.jpg) will be:

```
5
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Load the img
img = cv2.imread("MjfJF.png")

# Cvt to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Get binary-mask
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 0, 175]), np.array([179, 255, 255]))
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=1)
thr = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)

# OCR
d = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 10")
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your image has to be black on white.
You could also use another value for the psm argument.